# Is there a way to force specific order on extenders added to the same control?

Tags: asp.net

I wrote two control extenders that need to be placed always in the same order. Is there any way to make VS always place them in the correct order?

The only solution i found was to place them in a central repository keyed on the target control ID on their init stage - and then have each of them perform its work through that repository rather then directly. but this looks like an overly complex solution for me.

Anyone has a better idea?

Answer (score 1):

When you include one control extender do you always include the other? If so you combine them into one, so the dependency between them is removed? Or can you create a wrapping control extender that uses both of the separate control extenders. We do this with range type input where there needs to be beginning and ending fields.

Comment: the decision to use one or the other is completely independent - it is not that one of them always include the other (in that case a simple inheritance would sort it out

let me fill in a bit more details

both extenders react to the prerender event on the target control - and change attributes on that control in order to effect the generated html without effecting the data stored in the viewpage or session. both extenders in question effect the SAME property in different way (the Text property of a target label for example) - so the order between them is critical.

Comment: the problem is that to react to PreRender they need to register themselves in the delegate - and there is no order gurunteed by .net to the order in which different functions registered to the same delegate will be called.
all my tests so fur show that the actual order is the registration order - but i can't even rely on that since i do not know what order the developer added the two extenders in

Comment: so I see 3 options:
* use something else aside from extenders to do that
* publish some order/priority value in each extender that will be recognized by the framework
* have my extenders perform their job differently (not using delegates)

anyone else have a solution?